# why $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] change in mobile but not in pc?

Tags: php

I use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` for getting ip but in mobile, it changes each time but in pc it's not changing.
can anyone explain to me why this happens?

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>
```

Live Demo [here](http://lochawala.com/)

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Does-my-mobile-phone-have-a-fixed-IP-address-or-does-it-change-frequently

Comment: This has nothing to do with the mobile vs pc. It is just the mobile connection is either going through a cloud of proxy servers or keeps dropping its connection and is getting assigned a new IP address via DHCP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply:

Computer -> Sometimes dynamic IP, most of the time not, so it doesn't change.
Mobile -> Dynamic IP due to different positions, days, connection dropping/getting back
Works just as the position of the device basically: your computer, if it's not a laptop, won't change positions... but your phone always do as you move